# I've got error when i set debug to false after new update

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am currently learning python and django framework
Developing my article site i've discovered a problem

Here is my github repo: https://github.com/theseems/tsite

Well i've done my update replacing TinyMCE with CKEditor and when i set debug mode to False, i've got 500 error
I just tried to delete

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

And then it works. What is my problem about?

Comment: First of allí, welcome to SO. Everybody here started as a beginner so no need to say sorry and nobody should judge you for that. I upvoted your question. People Will be glad to help you.

Comment: I am sorry for this, my mistake

Comment: When you get a 500 error, you'll see in your console an error trace. Please paste the entire error stack trace in your question so we can figure out what the error is and where it occurs.

Comment: I would like to, but here is the log:
https://hastebin.com/alotuwasem.sql
It outputs nothing

Comment: Do you have DEBUG = True in your settings? And do you have a LOGGING setting in settings.py?

Comment: When i set debug to True, i get no errors. Actually, i have no LOGGING setting there. How to add it?

Comment: if debug is False, you need to run manage.py collectstatic (you're running in production then I assume) before you start your gunicorn/uwsgi server. And yes, you should have a LOGGING setting to log errors to file so you can at least look at the logs to see in production when an error is raised.

Comment: Read the entire [checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/#deployment-checklist) when deploying to a production environment.

Comment: The checklist link above has the links to the steps involved for static files and also for setting up LOGGING.

Comment: Thank you. I've just figured out what the problem was.  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "articles/favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">

Changed to

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">

Static could not find that file

Comment: still you should enable logging in production because it would show you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base.html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "articles/favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">
```

Changed to:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">
```

Static could not find that file so raised an error
Also, to avoid situations like this i've added logging to settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
  },
  'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
    },
  },
}
```

And followed the recomendations from

```
python manage.py check --deploy
```